# Is it safe to list optional fortran function argument in OpenMP shared clause?

Tags: fortran, openmp, optional-parameters

I write a Fortran code like the one shown below.

```fortran
module optional_arg
    contains

    subroutine foobar(opt_arg)
        integer, intent(in), optional :: opt_arg

        !$omp parallel default(none) shared(opt_arg)
        if (present(opt_arg)) then
        end if
        !$omp end parallel
    end subroutine foobar
end module optional_arg
```

The module has a function `foobar()` with an optional formal argument `opt_arg`. The subroutine contains an OpenMP-block. I need to list that optional argument in a `shared()` clause.

**Is that safe to do so?**

I was unable to find the answer in the official OpenMP 4.0 specifications. I am worried, because in a regular Fortran code it is not allowed to reference an optional variable unless it is actually present.

Upd.
Compilers do not complain:

- GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.10.0 20140718 (experimental): `gfortran -Wall -Wextra -fopenmp -c optional_arg.F90`
- NAG Fortran Compiler Release 6.0(Hibiya) Build 1042: `nagfor -openmp -c optional_arg.F90`

Comment: Interesting question.  What did your compiler say ?

Comment: Compilers do not complain (see my update to the question).

Comment: Fortran compilers usually pass arguments by address. An optional argument that is not present is simply passed as NULL pointer (or some other special value). As long as the internal realisation of the shared OpenMP variables is a block of pointers to the original variables and the compiler simply copies the value of each pointer, it should work.